# WebSocket connection to 'wss://[host]/' failed

Tags: amazon-web-services, websocket

#### Environment

First of all, I'm using AWS ALB, EC2 with Route 53. ALB is opened for HTTP, HTTPS and EC2 is also opened for All TCP.

And I'm using [`ws`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ws) library to use websocket.

#### As an HTTPS server

In the EC2 instance, when I run an HTTPS server which shows `"hello world"` as a text, it works well in a client using `https://`.

#### As an websocket server

However when I run an websocket server instead of HTTPS server and try to connect to that from a client, the below error occurs:

> WebSocket connection to 'wss://[host]/' failed

As a side note, in a client using `http://`, connecting to `ws://[same hostname]` works well.

What should I check? PLEASE HELP ME!

Comment: @MichaelHampton I'm using Node.js server with [`ws`](https://github.com/websockets/ws) websocket library and the socket server uses port 80. I know `wss://` uses 443 but ELB routes 433 to 80 so I use 80.

Comment: Check your application's logs, then.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I can't check any logs because the library prints nothing. :(

Comment: So basically you took just a library, wrote your code which doesn't works and you don't know how to debug it and now you are asking what's wrong? Even the simplest `ws` example right on the README has a `console.log` string which writes some debug info on connect. Rest is up to your code.

Comment: I'm sorry guys. this was my fault. An A record was wrong so the `wss` connection was failed. I'm sorry.

Comment: what exactly was wrong with A record?